# Compare 2 lists, specifying the selectors as parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have the following function

```
public static class ListUtils
{
    public static bool ListsHaveCommonality<T>(List<T> listOne, List<T> listTwo, Func<T, string> selectorOne, Func<T, string> selectorTwo)
    {
    return listOne.Select(selectorOne).Intersect(listTwo.Select(selectorTwo)).Any();
    }
}
```

Then a test to check it works

```
//Arrange
List<Alias> aliases = new List<Alias>();
Alias a1 = new Alias { alias = "test@test.com" };
Alias a2 = new Alias { alias = "test2@test.com" };
Alias a3 = new Alias { alias = "test3@test.com" };

aliases.Add(a1);
aliases.Add(a2);
aliases.Add(a3);

List<string> chosenAliases = new List<string>
            {
                "test@test.com",
                "test@something.com",
            };

//Act
bool hasCommonality = ListUtils.ListsHaveCommonality(aliases, chosenAliases, (Alias a) => a.alias, (string s) => s);

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(hasCommonality);
```

I get the following error

The type arguments for method System.Func, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: `ListsHaveCommonality` assumes that both lists have the same type parameter `T`.

Comment: Oh yeah. That's helped me correct it to 
`public static bool ListsHaveCommonality<T, T2>(List<T> listOne, List<T2> listTwo, Func<T, string> selectorOne, Func<T2, string> selectorTwo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListsHaveCommonality` assumes that both lists have the same type parameter `T`. If you want to use it with lists that have different item types, you need to create a method that supports two type parameters like this:

```
public static class ListUtils
{
    public static bool ListsHaveCommonality<T1,T2>(
        List<T1> listOne,
        List<T2> listTwo,
        Func<T1, string> selectorOne,
        Func<T2, string> selectorTwo)
    {
        return listOne.Select(selectorOne).Intersect(listTwo.Select(selectorTwo)).Any();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

listOne and listTwo are both defined as `List<T>`, but for the first you are sending `List<Alias>` and for the second you are sending `List<string>`.